# Docker Postgres service doesn't allow me to connect to it

Tags: node.js, docker

I created a `docker-composer.yml` file in which I added a Postgres service (v10.6). Everything goes smooth, but when I'm trying to connect ti it with the `User: postgres` and `Password: postgres` I get the following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "docker"
```

My code is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: "egn-postgres"
    image: "postgres:10.6"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try executing a `su - postgres` beforehand if you're trying to connect from the docker container itself (switch to postgres user). If you're trying to connect externally, check your users' identification method inside the postgresql configuration file (should be md5 if I remember correctly for password-based auth).

Comment: I will try, thank you!

Comment: Nope, same issue :(

Comment: That's odd, could you edit the question and post the way you're connecting to the postgresql instance in the question? You might not have a postgres user set up at all though..

Comment: I am using sequelize and on local host everything it's ok..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to put the environment variables, try this

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: "egn-postgres"
    image: "postgres:10.6"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

As @RickoThePow says, you have to define the environment variables.

You can use the solution presented by him:

```
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
```

or use a separated file (postgres.env) with:

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
```

and then invoke the file in docker-compose file like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: "egn-postgres"
    image: "postgres:10.6"
    .
    .
    .
    env_file: postgres.env
```